# Rigid type and equality check - is this possible in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Wondering is following code ever possible in Haskell?

```
equal :: a -> b -> Bool
equal a b = a == b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the type of `(==)` requires its arguments to be of the same type

```
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

You ask if it's possible (to test equality between different types), yes it is possible but not something you'd normally do. You can use [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html) to witness that `a` and `b` are the same type but you need a `Typeable` constraint on both of them (and `Eq` constraint on either)

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications    #-}
{-# Language ConstraintKinds     #-}
{-# Language GADTs               #-}

import Type.Reflection

type Equal a b = (Eq a, Typeable a, Typeable b)

equal :: forall a b. Equal a b => a -> b -> Bool
equal x y =
  case eqTypeRep (typeRep @a) (typeRep @b) of
    -- In this branch, `a' and `b' are the SAME type
    -- so `(==)' works
    Just HRefl -> x == y

    -- Values of different types are never equal
    Nothing -> False
```

so the following works

```
>> equal 10 'a'
False
>> equal 'X' 'a'
False
>> equal 'X' 'X'
True
```

Make sure you understand why we only constrain one of `Eq a`/`Eq b` and it doesn't matter which one.

Comment: I tried to run that code but got errors stating type variable a and b not in scope, details here -> https://pastebin.com/izWi4f9J

Comment: @DonKlein: It was missing the `forall` quantifier to define the scope of `a` and `b` with `ScopedTypeVariables`. (Works for me now.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `@` mean here?

Comment: @DonKlein `f x` applies value `x` to `f`, while `f @ a` applies _type_ (not value) `a` to `f`. The latter assumes that `f :: forall t. ....` and chooses `t` to be `a`. E.g. `id @ (Int, Bool) (3, True)` first specializes the identity on a pair type, and then applies it to a pair; here there is no actual need to specify `@(Int,Bool)` since the type inferer can infer that from `(3, True)`. Instead, above `typeRep` has no value arguments to drive the inference, and the type must be provided.

Comment: `typeRep @a` is same as `typeRep :: TypeRep a`, could have written: `eqTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep a) (typeRep :: TypeRep b)`. It's enabled by `:set -XTypeApplications` (in ghci) and is super useful

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, never thought by asking a question could learn so many tricks :)

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact `Eq` won't allow you to define that function due to `==`'s signature, you can define your own typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Eqq a b where
  eqq :: a -> b -> Bool

-- Just an example of a possible instance for general types
instance Eqq a b where
  eqq a b = True
```

And then,

```
equal :: (Eqq a b) => a -> b -> Bool
equal a b = a `eqq` b
```

Comment: @Iceland_jack it doesn't do what is expected, but you can equip the typeclass `Eqq` with your answer (great answer by the way) using `Typeable` to compare types and use `==` when both types are the same.

Comment: (Thanks) :) Ah I see